# Differences of geolocation accuracy between browsers

Tags: html, browser, geolocation

I try to know why when I use the geolocation with differents browsers on a same computer I have differents results. I know the implementation of the feature is not perfect..but,
it's strange because I try on a computer with chrome and FF4.1 and i got a good accuracy. On the same computer IE give me a bad accuracy. When I try on an other computer with chrome and FF 4.1, Chrome give me a good result and firefox the same bad accuracy as IE (ip location i guess ).

If anyone have a solution to get the same accuracy for all browser or just an explication ?

Comment: I've also noticed that sometimes Chrome will get me within 30 feet of where I'm sitting and other times it will be within 10 miles and all I've done is cleared my settings and refreshed. It's based on the information Google gathered when it did all the street view cars. They were picking up wifi hotspots so they are approximating your location. That doesn't fully explain why it's random, but I have noticed it is never that consisten, but better than most IP based tracking systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the location is computed using Google Street informations (wifi hotspots and cell phone repeaters).

For wifi, the geolocation module looks at signals received by the wifi adapter. Those signals are emitted from wifi access points. Google cars assessed the emission power of each access points, as well as their location, when driving around. From the relative strength of the signals received by the user wifi adapter, which is available to the geolocation module, the location of the wifi access points in sight, and their assumed transmission power, it is easy to determine where the user's wifi adapter is located.

However the computed position will varies if one of the received access point varies its own power, or is shadowed by something between it's antenna and the receiver's antenna.

Note that this will be similar when the geolocation is computed using cell phone signals.

If the location is done using GPS signal with a GPS receiver embedded in the computer, then your are back to general issue of GPS position determination (number of satellites in sight, their relative position, their height on the horizon, and signal reflexion). GPS normal accuracy is "within a radius of 30 m", that is 60 meters / 200 ft.

If the location determination is done using a mix of all available techniques, then the result will varies also according to the weight assigned to each technique in the final result.

Comment: I'm adding a comment to my answer to take into account recently reported privacy problems by Google/Apple. Android and iPhone seem to send home the list of Wifi/GSM access points and user in their proximity. This allows to guess the position of access points after (or without) the passage of Google cars. This also allows to track MAC address moves without the MAC's owner permission. With a MAC address you can visualize the user's moves. See "Family Finder app" on Google. Change "Family" by "anyone" to reflect the full extend of the application...