# What defines coords.accuracy in the Geolocation API when not using a positioning sensor?

Tags: html, browser, geolocation, desktop-application

I'm trying out [Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API-v2) with HTML5 and it seems the results are more [accurate](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API-v2/#accuracy) than it reports:

- `geolocation.coords.latitude` shows ~correct latitude
- `geolocation.coords.longitude` shows ~correct longitude
- `geolocation.address.street` + `geolocation.address.streetNumber` even shows the correct address.

However, the `geolocation.coords.accuracy` returns `18000` (meters), although the results are 1000× more accurate.

I'm not using any real positioning sensors, such as GPS, and currently testing the API on a desktop browser. I believe should there be a positioning sensor onboard, the accuracy value would be what the positioning sensor reports. But — **what defines the positioning accuracy when *no* positioning sensors are involved?** Is it merely a lucky guess by the browser? ("Better be sure than sorry?")

Is there a spec or a draft I could look into?

Comment: Related, but not strictly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6167948/216129

Comment: I'm also getting an accuracy value of 18000 with my Firefox/osx, which seems to be a not reliable value

Answer (score 1):

I think they give you 18,000 when you only submit one wifi_tower to thwart abuse. When you give it a list it returns smaller values, like 90. So, just knowing one AP is not enough, you have to know the environment.

User Agent might have something to do with it too.